# Sitecore XM Cloud local setup docker error

Tags: docker, xm-cloud

We are getting below mentioned error, while setting up `XM Cloud` on our local machine. Could you please suggest how we can resolve these issues?

> "dependency failed to start: container sxastarter-solr-1 is unhealthy"

Note:  I have  stopped all my solr service.

[image]

Comment: I am also facing same issue. But I could not find fix yet. But this seems quite relevant - https://blog.jermdavis.dev/posts/2022/docker-zookeeper-solr-fail .  I did not try that yet as it asks you to change docker files.

Comment: thanks. we tried this as well, not working.

Comment: Can you check what's the error in solr container?

Comment: HI Bala, thanks. below mentioned log details,

Comment: 2023-10-19 01:28:43 2023-10-18 19:58:43.068 WARN  (Thread-12) [   ] o.a.z.s.ServerCnxnFactory maxCnxns is not configured, using default value 0.
2023-10-19 01:28:43 2023-10-18 19:58:43.084 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.c.ConnectionManager Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper
2023-10-19 01:28:43 2023-10-18 19:58:43.123 WARN  (NIOWorkerThread-1) [   ] o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn Close of session 0x0 => java.io.IOException: ZooKeeperServer not running

Comment: 2023-10-19 01:28:43     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.readLength(NIOServerCnxn.java:544)
2023-10-19 01:28:43 java.io.IOException: ZooKeeperServer not running
2023-10-19 01:28:43     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.readLength(NIOServerCnxn.java:544) ~[?:?]
2023-10-19 01:28:43     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:332) ~[?:?]
2023-10-19 01:28:43     at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$IOWorkRequest.doWork(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:522) ~[?:?]

Comment: @gautam are you using docker cli?

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni -- no

Comment: Hi I had the same issue because I had a Solr Running on my local. I would said make sure you don't have a solr instance running in your local machine.

Comment: @PKH did you run the script as a admin mode right?

Comment: Hi, we find that issues. its not allowing, some of the external link access in my company laptop(its blocked, due security policy). we tried in our personal laptop, its working fine as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a conflict between your local setup and Traeffik. Ensure that you have executed "iisreset /stop" before running the "up.ps1."